# 14.04 - Getting 404 not found errors when doing 'sudo apt-get-update'

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, updates

Ubuntu 14.04.1

I am getting the following errors when doing sudo apt-get update.I haven't been able to fix this. Kindly help. I have copied the error output as follows -

```
Ign file:  InRelease
Ign file:  InRelease                                                           
Ign file:  InRelease                                                           
Ign file:  InRelease                                                           
Ign file:  InRelease                                                           
Get:1 file:  Release.gpg [181 B]                                               
Get:2 file:  Release.gpg [181 B]                                               
Get:3 file:  Release.gpg [819 B]                                               
Get:4 file:  Release.gpg [819 B]                                               
Get:5 file:  Release.gpg [819 B]                                               
Get:6 file:  Release [574 B]                                                   
Get:7 file:  Release [347 B]                                                   
Get:8 file:  Release [1,999 B]                                                 
Get:9 file:  Release [2,003 B]                                                 
Get:10 file:  Release [2,008 B]                                                
Ign file:  Translation-en_US                                                   
Ign file:  Translation-en                                                      
Ign file:  Translation-en_US                                                   
Ign file:  Translation-en                                                      
Ign file:  Translation-en_US                                                   
Ign file:  Translation-en                                                      
Ign file:  Translation-en_US                                                   
Ign file:  Translation-en                                                      
Ign file:  Translation-en_US                                                   
Ign file:  Translation-en                                                      
Hit http://packages.ros.org trusty InRelease                                   
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                              
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Hit http://packages.ros.org trusty/main amd64 Packages                         
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                    
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://packages.osrfoundation.org trusty InRelease                         
Hit http://packages.ros.org trusty/main arm64 Packages                         
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                  
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease [65.9 kB]          
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Hit http://packages.ros.org trusty/main i386 Packages                          
Hit http://packages.osrfoundation.org trusty/main amd64 Packages               
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://packages.osrfoundation.org trusty/main arm64 Packages               
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease [65.9 kB]         
Get:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease [21.4 kB]                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources [132 kB]        
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                    
Hit http://packages.osrfoundation.org trusty/main i386 Packages                
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources [4,955 B] 
Get:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed InRelease [65.9 kB]        
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                               
Get:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease [15.5 kB]                     
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources [59.4 kB]   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Ign http://packages.ros.org trusty/main Translation-en_US                      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex              
Ign http://packages.ros.org trusty/main Translation-en                         
Get:19 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources [3,200 B] 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources                 
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US                         
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources           
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main arm64 Packages/DiffIndex              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources             
Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages [621 kB] 
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources           
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex               
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages          
Get:21 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages [14.0 kB]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages      
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages [173 kB]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Get:23 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [4,135 B]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex              
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main arm64 Packages/DiffIndex              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages           
Ign http://packages.osrfoundation.org trusty/main Translation-en_US            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex               
Get:24 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages [579 kB]  
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages       
Ign http://packages.osrfoundation.org trusty/main Translation-en               
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main arm64 Packages                        
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.152 80]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en          
Get:25 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages [13.7 kB]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Get:26 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages [173 kB]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en    
Get:27 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages [4,290 B]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en             
Get:28 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [14.3 kB]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en       
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages [417 kB]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main arm64 Packages                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                     
Get:30 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages [988 kB]
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                        
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main arm64 Packages             
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted arm64 Packages       
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe arm64 Packages         
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main arm64 Packages                        
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse arm64 Packages       
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Get:31 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [17.1 kB]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Get:32 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [14.6 kB]
Get:33 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages [418 kB]
Get:34 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages [943 kB]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_US                     
Get:35 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages [16.9 kB]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_US                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en    
Get:36 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/multiverse amd64 Packages [28 B]
Get:37 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/universe amd64 Packages [12.4 kB]
Get:38 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/main amd64 Packages [88.1 kB]
Get:39 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/restricted amd64 Packages [769 B]
Get:40 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/multiverse i386 Packages [28 B]
Get:41 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/universe i386 Packages [12.4 kB]
Get:42 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/main i386 Packages [85.8 kB]
Get:43 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/restricted i386 Packages [772 B]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/universe Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources                       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages               
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages               
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main arm64 Packages          
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted arm64 Packages    
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe arm64 Packages      
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse arm64 Packages    
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse arm64 Packages      
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe arm64 Packages        
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main arm64 Packages            
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted arm64 Packages      
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/multiverse arm64 Packages     
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/universe arm64 Packages       
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/main arm64 Packages           
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/restricted arm64 Packages     
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main arm64 Packages                    
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted arm64 Packages              
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe arm64 Packages                
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse arm64 Packages              
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                 
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US           
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US           
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US             
Fetched 5,044 kB in 10s (499 kB/s)                                             
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY FCAE110B1118213C
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C2518248EEA14886
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/restricted/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/universe/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/multiverse/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/restricted/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/universe/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/multiverse/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/multiverse/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/restricted/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-proposed/multiverse/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-proposed/universe/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-proposed/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-proposed/restricted/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/multiverse/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I am also copying my /etc/apt/sources.list -

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20160803)]/ trusty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse universe main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed multiverse universe main restricted
```

Comment: Please include the output of command `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`

Comment: look in /etc/apt/sourse.d directory for files that have the ignored/incorrect links

Comment: Navigate to the address 91.189.91.23 in your browsers and post the results in a comment the site may be blocked on your network

Comment: @steeldriver It outputs the following -

**i386
arm64**

Comment: @9291Sam The site doesn't seem to be blocked

Comment: I'm wondering *why* you have the arm64 foreign architecture enabled - do you remember why you added that?

Comment: @steeldriver I used this computer as a host machine for installing Jetson L4T

Comment: OK - nevertheless the "standard" repos don't appear to provide packages for that architecture (they appear to be at ports.ubuntu.com)

Comment: hi, the post from this link helps me remove similar issue `apt-get remove .*:arm64 `, 
`dpkg --remove-architecture arm64 `, reference `http://blog.csdn.net/qq_29573053/article/details/71515714`